# How to use spaced repetition and active recall help to learn new topics, rather than just memorize them

Tags: learning

I’ve used spaced repetition and active recall help to memorize things that I already understand. It has been helpful to me.

Here is how I did it-:

1. I UNDERSTAND something.
2. I write short notes (version 1).
3. I read version 1 notes. And again write some notes (version 2).
4. I read notes version 2.
5. I again write notes (version 3) and read them.

I keep doing this as much time I have. Generally doing this for 3 times ensures I remember everything. But that doesn't really help with learning new content.

**How can I use this to learn new topics?**

Comment: You have used this before apparently, so how did you use it then? I assume also on a new topic, right?

Comment: i used it on already understood topic to memorize. huge difference.

Comment: What sort of thing do you think you need to "memorize"?

Comment: I mean I am studying for university exam, so I need to memorize.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is an important part of learning, but not all of it. There are many techniques to help you remember stuff, but you're forgetting another important aspect of learning: **practice**.

*Employing* whatever you're trying to learn also helps with learning.